# Axios error generated while using chatgpt api in creating the web project using MERN

Tags: node.js, postman, openai-api

{
"message": "AxiosError: Request failed with status code 429",
"stack": "Error: AxiosError: Request failed with status code 429\n    at C:\Users\HP\OneDrive\Desktop\AIGEN\AIGEN_backend\controllers\openAIController.js:43:15\n    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)"
}

i got this error ...please help me to solve this error .
this error is generated due to following provided code :

```
const asyncHandler = require('express-async-handler')
const axios = require('axios');
const User = require('../models/User');
const ContentHistory = require('../models/ContentHistory');



// open Ai controller

const openAIController = asyncHandler(async(req,res)=>{
    console.log(req.user);
    const {prompt} = req.body;
    try{
       const response = await axios.post('https://api.openai.com/v1/completions',{
           model:'gpt-3.5-turbo-instruct',
           prompt,
           max_tokens:25,
       },{
        headers:{
            Authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY}`,
            'Content-Type':"application/json",
        },  
       }
       );


       // send the response
        const content = response?.data?.choices[0].text?.trim();
        // create the hisory
        const newContent = await ContentHistory.create({
          user: req?.user?._id,
          content,
      });
      // push the content into the user
        const userFound = await User.findById(req?.user?.id);
        userFound.history.push(newContent?._id);
        userFound.apiRequestCount+=1
        await userFound.save();
        res.status(200).json(content);
    }
    catch(error){
        console.log(error);
        throw new Error(error);
    }
});


module.exports = {
    openAIController,
}
```

i am making one website in which i am using chatgpt api ...but i got this error

Answer (score 0):

The above error suggests that you have used your free or paid limit of your Open AI api.

This may be caused if you are using a free version and you have exceeded your time limit, as i think Open AI have some time limit before that only it have free usage.

You can check the limits [here](https://www.scriptbyai.com/rate-limits-openai-api/)